# Protostar menu problem on mobile devices

Tags: joomla-3.4, menu, mobile-web-design

I had built a multilingual Joomla 3.4.1 site last week, it uses a modified version of Protostar template with horizontal menu (" nav-pills"). When I'm browsing my site on PC it's okay:
[image: PC browser 800+ px]

Under width:768px my menu partially disappears, I can see only the active item:
[image: Under 768px]

On PC I can see menu items when I'm hovering with my mouse but on mobile devices in portrait mode I can not hover because there is no mouse. I just can click somewhere and the site or a sub-menu will load.
[image: on hover]
[image: iPhone portrait]

How can I fix the menu on mobile devices if in portrait mode width is lower than 768 px?

Comment: Do you have any live url to see the problem?

Comment: Does it work properly in Protostar (unmodified)? I suspect that the issue is probably with your modifications. As others have already pointed out, we can't provide a fix without knowing what the issue is, and we can't do by looking at screenshots.

Comment: URL is [link](http://www.lkg-delta.hu/index.php/hu)
Yes, it does work with original Protostar properly.
Now, I have fixed the code it was site specific. The bottom of header image is #000066 but menu items background-color was inherited (white). I've added background-color: #000066; to line #2963 and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you any specific code as you have provided any of your own, nor a link to your site for a live preview, but to answer your question in regards to targeting a width of lower than 768px with the orientation as portrait, you can use the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .nav-pills > li > a {
        background-color: #1947d1;
        border-right: 4px solid #ed1c24;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. URL is [link](http://www.lkg-delta.hu/index.php/hu)
I just tried "and (orientation: portrait)" code but it doesn't really helps.

Comment: @Vikitorony - I've updated my answer with the code. Add it your your template CSS file